# Is pg-promise supports multiple host addresses(primary and secondary) in connection string?

Tags: postgresql, pg-promise

As per postgresql documentation, we can use the multiple hosts(primary and secondary) in connection string.We are using pg-promise node driver to run postgresql queries.As far i know pg-promise doesn't supporting multiple hosts.If anyone used this multi host mechanism.Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying driver `node-postgres` / `pg` does not support it, and so `pg-promise` does not support it either. Hopefully, in the future.